# I am trying to divide in MARS MIPS but it's giving me the wrong answer

Tags: assembly, mars-simulator

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter your first number:"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter your second number:"
.text
main:

#displays "Enter your first number:"
li $v0 4
la $a0 prompt1
syscall

#Reads the next int and stores in $s0
li $v0 5
syscall
move $s0 $v0

#displays "Enter your second number:"
li $v0 4
la $a0 prompt2
syscall

#Reads next int and stores in $s1
li $v0 5
syscall 
move $s1 $v0


#Divides user input $s0/$s1 and stores in $t0
div $t0 $s0 $s1
syscall


#Print value of $t0
li $v0 1
move $t0 $v0
syscall

li $v0 10
syscall
```

The goal of my code is to ask the user for 2 inputs and take those two inputs and divide them. However, when I run the program in input "1" my output is a really high number.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things:

1. There's an extra syscall after the division instruction.
2. When you want to print the value of $t0, recall that the print_int syscall will print whatever is in $a0, not $t0.  Right now, the contents of $v0 (which is 1) are moved into $t0, but the print_int syscall is printing $a0, which is garbage.

Try this instead (in addition to removing the extra syscall above):

```
#Print value of $t0
li $v0 1
move $a0 $t0
syscall
```

Hope that helps.